# Trying to delete a file - get Access is Denied

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Windows 7 - Running under an Administrator account, trying to delete a file on a mapped network drive - get **Access is Denied**.  From the cmd prompt:

```
S:\SharedFiles\temp>del 20151121_142409.mp4
S:\SharedFiles\temp\20151121_142409.mp4
Access is denied.
```

Using Process Explorer (started as Admin) doing a Find (Handle or DLL substring) get "0 matching items".    I've also rebooted, and closed and restarted Explorer.

Please don't suggest third-party tools like "unlocker" - there are apparently many malware-infected versions of it floating around the web, and these have been widely-reported even here on superuser.com

This is a factory-installed Windows 7.

For checking permissions on a file, Microsoft says (In https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc753659.aspx )

```
Right-click the file or folder, and then click Properties. 
Click the  Security tab. 
Under Group or user names, click your name to see the permissions you have.
```

... when I do that the only tabs I see are General, Properties, Previous Versions.  (no Security tab).   **None** of the files on my mapped drive have security tabs but there's no trouble deleting, renaming or otherwise manipulating them, just this one file.

As you can see by the list of things I've tried I've looked at lots of similar posts, so if you think this might be a "duplicate" please indicate which its a duplicate of.

Comment: Most likely you are administrator on your machine but that doesn't mean you are a domain administrator. There's a difference. To find out who has the file opened, you need to go to the server/computer where the share points at and start process monitor on that machine (or look at Open Files in de Shared Folders of the Computer Management window)

Comment: I don't know what you mean "go to the server/computer where the share points at".   It's just an NAS (i.e., a harddrive with an Ethernet interface).   The only PC on the network is the one I'm using.

Comment: Ah that wasn't obvious to me but nevertheless, if it's a network drive, you should have *some* interface to manage that drive. Be it through http, putty or, heaven forbid, telnet.